# React app without server

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

How can a react application be packaged and hosted without a server. The application is purely front end.
Tried building the application `npm run build` but that created a build which would require a server to be hosted on.

Answer (score 1):

Well no, it doesn't require a server to host it. As you said its just front end. HOWEVER, if you want to navigate OTHER than via scripted navigation you'll need a server. Simply building your project and serving the index file as a static asset is sufficient to run the code on shared hosting. Once the index file has finished downloading it will execute the javascript thats imported (react in this case). but if you try to go to say, website.com/blah its not going to work as rendering specific routes in react requires rendering and returning javascript. Something you need a server for.

The react bundle is self executing, at least with create-react-app. You shouldn't have any issues.

Comment: ps please clarify if what you really mean is "how can i host my react app on my own computer for people to view" because thats totally different than how I'm interpreting your question which is "do i need a dedicated hosting server for my app"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a http server to host the site locally. But if you want to host it on the cloud, there are other options.

Once you have it bundled. You just have to copy the assets to a bucket on  Amazon S3. It allows you to serve them as a static website. You can refer more information here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Similarly other Cloud providers have their own equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

You can not load anything by `http(s):` protocol without server by definition. Possible you mean loading by url like `file:` which is local file system path.

Bundle builded to load assets by absolute url. It is because your pages may have some deep path in url. So you need to configure server so your build folder will be as root of site.

This mean if you try to run it from disk on workstation you need to put content of your build directory to root of disk to work (`C:\` for example if windows, or `/` if you not on windows)